# Return value from node.js fiber future

Tags: javascript, node.js, future, synchronous, node-fibers

In the following piece of code the fiber works as expected ("1" and "2" are printed 2 seconds apart). But, I want to return "3" from fiberFunction and print that synchronously. This doesn't work though.Here is the output:

```
1
Temp: undefined
2
```

Does anybody know how to return a value from a fiber function?

```
var Fiber = require('fibers');
var Future = require('fibers/future'), wait = Future.wait;

function sleep(ms) {
    var future = new Future;
    setTimeout(function() {
        future.return();
    }, ms);
    return future;
}

var fiberFunction = Fiber(function() {
    console.log("1");
    sleep(2000).wait();
    console.log("2");
    return "3";
});

var fiberReturn = fiberFunction.run();
console.log("Temp: " + fiberReturn);
```

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that `fiberFunction` is not a function, it is a fiber instance, and fiber instances don't return anything. Also, you should not use Future.wait directly — you should only wait on instances.

You should instead be doing this:

```js
var Fiber = require('fibers')
var Future = require('fibers/future')

function sleep(ms) {
    var future = new Future
    setTimeout(function() {
        future.return()
    }, ms)
    return future
}

var yourFunction = function() {
    console.log("1")
    sleep(2000).wait()
    console.log("2")
    return "3"
}

Fiber(function() {   
    console.log("Temp: " + yourFunction())
}).run()
```

I'd recommend you read the [README documentation](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) thoroughly before using Fibers or futures in earnest.

---

This was copied from [node-fibers issue #171](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/issues/171) because many people end up here instead. Originally written by `fresheneesz`.